# Notations for Orbits, Stabilizers, Centralizers, Conjugation Classes, and the Center of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-actions

I'm trying to understand these different aspects of group actions and the thing that's throwing me off the most is the notation for these sets. Additionally, when browsing other stack exchange questions and wikipedia articles, the notions aren't grouped together so it I can't compare one notation to another. Could someone please provide the common notations for the above sets to help clarify what notation goes with what? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *orbit* of a group action of $G$ on an element $x$ of a set $X$ is often denoted by $$G_X(x).$$ (See, for example, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html).)

The *stabiliser* of an element $x$ of a set $X$ by a group action of $G$ is often denoted by $$\operatorname{Stab}_G(x).$$ (See, for example, [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Stabilizer).)

The *centraliser* of a subset $S$ of a group $G$ is denoted by $$C_G(S).$$ (See, for example, [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer).)

The *conjugacy class* of an element $g$ of a group $G$ is often denoted $$\operatorname{Cl}_G(g).$$ (See, for example, [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class).)

The *centre* of a group $G$ is denoted by $$Z(G).$$ This is universal notation and can be found anywhere.

Comment: I would just point out that your notation for orbit suggests that you are using left actions. I guess (and I find it unfortunate that) left actions are used more frequently than right actions in taught courses on group actions, but people ought to be aware of the fact that many of us who do research in this area prefer to use right actions. Also both of the most commonly used computing systems for group theory, GAP and Magma, use right actions. I generally use $x^G$ for the orbit of $G$ that contains $x$.